# CPU usage of my app. goes to high?

Tags: android, error-handling, bitmap

In My application( PhotoCrop) i am getting force close after 4 or 5 images was used at a time. 
in the TaskManager it shows     **RAM :30 Mb and CPU:(varies 10 to 20%)**. it show's three different colors (Red, yellow, blue).

I am not getting Where is the problem, the error is (  **Vm budget exceed's** )
i am using some Bitmap's in the programming i have added this line to bitmap's after usage over.

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

still i am not able to solve this problem.

please tell me how can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be doing something like this:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("test");
//doing something with the bitmap
b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("test2");
//and so on
b.recycle();
```

That sample will keep the reference to the first bitmap and will not be garbage collected. The second one will. So you have to remember to b.recycle(); before you load a new bitmap.